# How to save various scale,rotation and translation states of a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone

I have a UIImageView and I have a NSMutableArray. I apply scale,rotation and translation operations on pinch-zoom, rotate and pan gestures.

at various stages I save this state in the array.

I display a table where on tapping on a row I set that particular transform of the UIImageView
from the array which I had added when I captured the state.

Now when I set back the transform, the image comes to the correct scale and rotation level but not in the correct postion (translation).